# c struct, 2 variable assigment types

Tags: c, pointers, struct, variable-assignment

Why do assignments of 'num' to my_struct and my_confusing differ in the function use_struct()?  For that matter, why I assign 'num' to my_struct using both "." & "->" notation?  This must be because of scope, but don't I have a reference to the structure in both places?  What is the difference between my_struct in main vs. inside of use_struct()?

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Test{
    int num;
};

void use_number(struct Test my_struct){

    // is VALUE therefore "."
    my_struct.num = 99999; 
    printf("inside use number the value is %d\n", my_struct.num);
    // this takes in a COPY of structure, cannot modify orig 

}

void use_struct(struct Test *my_struct){
    // take in a pointer to test, 
    // here I CAN CHANGE THE VALUE OF TEST
    // HAVE POINTER THEREFORE "->"
    my_struct->num +=1;
    printf("inside use_struct the value is %d\n", my_struct->num);

    struct Test confusing ;

    confusing.num = 88888; 
    printf("here you assign a number differently to my_confusing %d \n",     confusing.num);

    printf("Why do assignment of num to my_stuct and confusing differ");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    struct Test my_struct;

    my_struct.num = 5;
    printf("Begin as %d\n", my_struct.num);

    // Pass in the ACTUAL THING
    use_struct(&my_struct);
    printf("after use_struct: %d\n", my_struct.num); // dot here b/c you want to print the NUMBER, not the box that contains it 

    // pass in a COPY
    use_number(my_struct);
    printf("after use number %d\n", my_struct.num);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Because one is a pointer and the other one isn't?

Comment: This program won't even compile; maybe show us the code you're actually using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main func. you use a  (.) to assign a value to struct.
In main (my_struct) is local variable. U pass by reference to your func (use_struct). With & you send to func only address of the struct. So in your use_struct function you have to dereference it.

my_struct->num is equivalent to (*my_struct).num

Then in your func you create new struct  my_confusion. This struct is a local struct. It is not pointer to struct so after the end of the function it dissapear. Try to do something with my_confusion in main. You will get an error thar this struct is not declared.

So in use_struct func

my_struct is pointer and to access elements you use ->
my_confusion is local struct created in func. and to access elements you use .

you can learn ore here https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-structures-pointers

Comment: tyvm, I guess what I didn't/(don't) understand is that there is a third thing.  1) the value "7".  2) the pointer, a_box_that_contains_an_integer and, 3)... what is the third thing? I guess memory locations in local scope are not pointers?  Wait,  I only need the pointer when I am pointing to something outside the current stackframe?  A pointer only points to memory outside the current stack?